# Using awk to calculate and print the average of values obtained via regular expression

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file named bt.B.1.log that looks like this:

```
.
.
.
Time in seconds =                   260.37
.
.
.
Time in seconds =                   260.04
.
.
.
```

and so on for 40 records of Time in seconds (dots represent useless lines).
I'm supposed to extract those times from the file and calculate/print the average to a .dat file (t1avg.dat) without using intermediate files.
I've been able to do so using intermediate files:

```
awk '/Time in seconds/ {print $5}' bt.B.1.log > t1.dat
awk '{sum+=$0} END {print sum/NR}' t1.dat > t1avg.dat
```

So the approach is to somehow pass the regular expression that appears in the first awk command as a parameter in the second command, telling awk to calculate the sum over the resulting lines of the regular expression, all reading from a single file (bt.B.1.log) and writing to t1avg.dat (suppressing the creation of t1.dat). So far I've reached the following code, which is giving the wrong output:

```
awk '{sum+=/Time in seconds/$5; print sum/NR}' bt.B.1.log
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/Time in seconds/ {s+=$5;c++} END{print s/c}' bt.B.1.log >t1avg.dat
```

`s` is the sum of the times and `c` is the count.  Thus, `s/c` is the average.

Comment: Consider `awk -F= '/Time in seconds/ {s+=$2; c++} END{print s/c}'` if the format is the same as the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can split on `=` as well:

```
$ echo "$e"
.
.
.
Time in seconds =                   260.37
.
.
.
Time in seconds =                   260.04
.
$ echo "$e" | awk -F= '/Time in seconds/ {s+=$2; c++} END{print s/c}'
260.205
```